# Incremental MS Build

Tags: msbuild, msbuild-task

New to MSbuild 
I want to create a Incremental MSbuild Task which does follows

1. Take Latest by Changeset(Done)
2. Create Items of all updated/added/Deleted files
3. Create output files base on input files.

Comment: Did you try anything?

Comment: @ByeBye: yes the whole build and deploy process is done but problem is, every time its building whole solution and copying all files even one CS file is changed so I wanted to incorporate Incremental build which i dont have any idea

Comment: Does your solution build all projects when just building twice from Visual Studio or from MSBuild command line?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show [what you have tried so far](http://whathaveyoutried.com).  You should include a [mcve] of the code that you are having problems with, then we can try to help with the specific problem. You should also read [ask].